# alfresco selectone (dropdown list) not work

Tags: eclipse, forms, share, config, alfresco

I did not correctly displayed
DropDown List in Alfresco Share. I did everything as shown in the video (Alfresco Summit 2013 ), but after deployment from Eclipse is obtained as in the image below. Prompt please who knows the solution. Thank you!

[Image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH49z.jpg)
[Image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngm6f.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you please post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please add steps which you did.contact me at krutik.jayswal@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thanks, the problem is solved!
It was necessary to manually add the path to the template file and describe the parameters in the file config-custom.xml (%Alfresco%\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension)

It was:

```
<field set="info" label-id="Value select" id="hire:valueselect"/>
```

After the change:

```
<field set="info" label-id="Value select" id="hire:valueselect">
<control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/selectone.ftl">
    <control-param name="options">Sales,Support,Engineering,Marketing</control-param>
</control>
```

[Screen Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG43P.jpg)